# Cassandra data modeling understanding

Tags: cassandra, cql

I came from SQL and switched now to CQL. I don't quite understand something yet.

In SQL this works:

```
Table product
id,
 name, 
 desc,
 price

Table cart
  id 
  item_id

SELECT
  p.name,
  p.desc,
  p.price

FROM product

INNER JOIN cart
ON c.item_id = p.id
```

But in Cassandra is it different or I am wrong?
Can I do his in Cassandra too, or is that bad?
How you would query multiple tables in Cassandra?

Comment: basically, write your queries 1st and design tables to answer the queries. Please de-normalize tables and don't worry too much about replication of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cassandra, you'll want to start with building a table to support your query:

```
SELECT * FROM product
INNER JOIN cart
ON c.item_id = p.id
```

Of course there aren't any joins, so we'll have to build a table to store that cart-product data:

```
CREATE TABLE cart_product (
    product_name TEXT,
    product_desc TEXT,
    product_price DECIMAL,
    product_id uuid,
    cart_id uuid,
    qty int,
    PRIMARY KEY (cart_id,product_id)
);
```

By defining my primary key like this, I'm ensuring that all of my rows will be stored together by `cart_id`.  As it's the first primary key, it becomes the *partitioning* key.  As I intend to have more than one product per cart, `product_id` needs to be a part of the key as a clustering column to ensure uniqueness.

After inserting some data, this works:

```
> SELECT product_name,product_price,product_desc 
  FROM cart_product
  WHERE cart_id=93aefdf3-acbf-4d3c-849c-4db9b2ef9e19;

 product_name         | product_price | product_desc
----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------
            Minecraft |         29.99 | Build the future with blocks, and try not to die!
 Kerbal Space Program |         29.99 |         Blast into space.  Now with moar rockets!
       Cyberpunk 2077 |         59.99 |         Wake up Samurai.  We have a city to burn!

(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Have understand this but how I can speak to another table ? I mean if I want add a userid to see which user created a cart.

Comment: @localdata01 you cannot.  You need to know all your queries up front, and build a table to support it.

Comment: @localdata01 In retrospect, you could accomplish that by adding a new column and building a secondary index on it.  But that won’t perform well.

Comment: I read that cassandra is not good for payment transaction and a lot of updates. Should I use RDBMS ?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra doesn't have joins, so you can't do it - if you need to perform the join, then it should be done in your application.

Cassandra encourages the data denormalization, when you can copy necessary data into another table to avoid joining when reading data - like, for `cart` table, you can copy price/description from the `product` table, and then when displaying the cart you won't need to query the `product` table.

I recommend to read first chapters of "Casasndra: The Definitive Guide, 3rd edition" book - it's [freely available](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide). This will help you with understanding how to model data for Cassandra

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take time to read that book but before can you say me how I copy it?

Comment: basically, your cart table besides `id`, `item_id` needs to include also relevant columns from the `product` table, ie: `price` & `name`

Comment: I mean a code example how I copy a table with cassandra the syntax ^^

Comment: You need to do that with code, or using tools like DSBulk